# BeautifulSoup4 and Pandas return back Empty DataFrame Columns: update: now using Selenium on Google-Colab

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am looking for a public list of world banks

I don't need branch offices and full addresses - but the name and the website. I think of data ... XML, CSV ... with these fields:
bank name, country name or country code (ISO two letters) website: optional: city of bank headquarters For each bank, one record per country of presence. **btw:** especially small banks are interesting

i have found a great page that is very very comprehensive - see - it has got 9000 banks in Europe:

see  from a to z:

https://thebanks.eu/search

```
**A**
https://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Albania
https://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Andorra
https://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Anguilla

**B**
https://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Belgium


**U** 
https://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Ukraine
https://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=United+Kingdom
```

see a detailed page: https://thebanks.eu/banks/9563

i need to have this data
**Contacts**

```
Mitteldorfstrasse 48, 9524, Zuzwil SG, Switzerland
071 944 15 51071 944 27 52
https://www.bankbiz.ch/
```

approach: my approach is to use bs4, request and pandas

**btw**: perhaps we can count form zero to 100 000 - in order to get all the bank that are stored inthe db:

see a detailed page: https://thebanks.eu/banks/9563

i run on colab this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Function to scrape bank data from my URL
def scrape_bank_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    # here we try to find bank name, country, and website
    bank_name = soup.find("h1", class_="entry-title").text.strip()
    country = soup.find("span", class_="country-name").text.strip()
    website = soup.find("a", class_="site-url").text.strip()
    print(f"Scraped: {bank_name}, {country}, {website}")

    return {"Bank Name": bank_name, "Country": country, "Website": website}

# the list of URLs for scraping bank data by country
urls = [
    "https://thebanks.eu/search",
    "https://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Albania",
    "https://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Andorra",
    #  we could add more URLs for other countries as needed
]

# List to store bank data
bank_data = []

# Iterate through the URLs and scrape bank data
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    bank_links = soup.find_all("div", class_="search-bank")

    for bank_link in bank_links:
        bank_url = "https://thebanks.eu" + bank_link.find("a").get("href")
        bank_info = scrape_bank_data(bank_url)
        bank_data.append(bank_info)

#  and now we convert the list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(bank_data)

# subsequently we print the DataFrame
print(df)
```

see what is getting back

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

well it seems to me that there is an issue with the scraping process. i tried some  different approachs by inspecting the elements on the webpage again  and again to ensure i am extracting the correct information on the page.

well should also print out some extra debug information to help diagnose the problem.

**update:** good evening dear @Asish M. and  @eternal_white
thank you very much for your comments and for sharing your ideas: Food for thoughts:  As for the Selenium - i think that this is a good idea - and for running it (selenium) on Google-Colab i have learned from Jacob Padilla
@Jacob / @user:21216449 :: see Jacobs page:  https://github.com/jpjacobpadilla with the Google-Colab-Selenium: https://github.com/jpjacobpadilla/Google-Colab-Selenium and the default Options:

```
The google-colab-selenium package is preconfigured with a set of default options optimized for Google Colab environments. These defaults include:
    • --headless: Runs Chrome in headless mode (without a GUI). 
    • --no-sandbox: Disables the Chrome sandboxing feature, necessary in the Colab environment. 
    • --disable-dev-shm-usage: Prevents issues with limited shared memory in Docker containers. 
    • --lang=en: Sets the language to English.
```

well i think that this approach is worth to think about: so we can go like so:

were using Selenium in Google Colab to bypass the Cloudflare (that you mentioned - eternal_white) blocking and scrape the desired data can be nice but feasible approach. Here some thoughts on a step-by-step aproach - and how to set it up using the google-colab-selenium package by Jacob Padilla:

```
Install google-colab-selenium:
You can install the google-colab-selenium package using pip:

diff
```

!pip install google-colab-selenium

we also need to install Selenium:

diff

```
!pip install selenium

Import Necessary Libraries:
Import the required libraries in your Colab notebook:

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from google.colab import output
import time
```

and then we need to setup Selenium WebDriver:
Configure the Chrome WebDriver with the necessary options:

```
# Set up options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
```

here we re going to define Function for Scraping:
we define a function to scrape bank data using Selenium:

```
def scrape_bank_data_with_selenium(url):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)  # first of all - we let the page load completely
    
    bank_name = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'entry-title').text.strip()
    country = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'country-name').text.strip()
    website = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'site-url').text.strip()
    print(f"Scraped: {bank_name}, {country}, {website}")

    return {"Bank Name": bank_name, "Country": country, "Website": website}
```

and then we could go and scrape Data: Now we can scrape the data using the defined function:

```
# List of URLs for scraping bank data by country
urls = [
    "https://thebanks.eu/search",
    "https://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Albania",
    "https://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Andorra",
    # hmm - we could add more URLs for other countries as needed
]

# List to store bank data
bank_data = []

# now we can iterate through the URLs and scrape bank data
for url in urls:
    bank_data.append(scrape_bank_data_with_selenium(url))

# and now we can convert the list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(bank_data)

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)
```

and - in one **single shot:**

```
# first of all we need to install all the required packages - for example the Packages of Jakobs Selenium approach etc etx: 
!pip install google-colab-selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin

# and afterwards we need to import all the necessary libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import time

# Set up options for Chrome WebDriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')  # Add this option

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

# Define function to scrape bank data using Selenium
def scrape_bank_data_with_selenium(url):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)  # Let the page load completely
    
    bank_name = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'entry-title').text.strip()
    country = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'country-name').text.strip()
    website = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'site-url').text.strip()
    print(f"Scraped: {bank_name}, {country}, {website}")

    return {"Bank Name": bank_name, "Country": country, "Website": website}

# List of URLs for scraping bank data by country
urls = [
    "https://thebanks.eu/search",
    "https://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Albania",
    "https://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Andorra",
    # Add more URLs for other countries as needed
]

# List to store bank data
bank_data = []

# Iterate through the URLs and scrape bank data
for url in urls:
    bank_data.append(scrape_bank_data_with_selenium(url))

# Convert the list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(bank_data)

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)

# Close the WebDriver
driver.quit()
```

see what i have **got back** - on **google-colab:**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-4-76a7abf92dba> in <cell line: 21>()
     19 
     20 # Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
---> 21 driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
     22 
     23 # Define function to scrape bank data using Selenium

TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'
```

**update**: btw if we want to gather data form all the countries we can go like so:

```
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Albania"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Andorra"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Anguilla"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Austria"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Belgium"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Bermuda"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Bosnia and Herzegovina"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=British Virgin Islands"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Bulgaria"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Cayman Islands"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Croatia"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Curacao"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Cyprus"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Czech Republic"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Denmark"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Estonia"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Finland"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=France"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Georgia"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Germany"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Gibraltar"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Greece"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Guernsey"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Hungary"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Iceland"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Ireland"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Isle of Man"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Italy"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Jersey"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Latvia"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Liechtenstein"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Lithuania"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Luxembourg"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Macedonia"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Malta"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Monaco"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Montenegro"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Netherlands"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Norway"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Poland"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Portugal"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Romania"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=San Marino"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Serbia"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Slovakia"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Slovenia"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Spain"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country= Sweden"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Switzerland"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Turkey"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Turks and Caicos Islands"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Ukraine"
"http://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=United Kingdom"
```

Comment: Have you checked where you're getting blanks? is it the `bank_links` line vs is it the `scape_bank_data` function. On my end it looks to be the former - and you may be getting blocked

Comment: hi there - good day dear Asish M .  thank you very much for the reply - as for the "Being-Blocked-thing" well at the moment i have runned this on the google-colab-account -but i can do a try on the notebook - where i have installed pycharm. 

I will digg deeper later the day. At the moment i am on the train ... 
thank you so much for the ideas - i look forward to solve this issue

Comment: again dear Asish - one minor idea regarding the iteration over all the pages. can we do this like so: can  we count form zero to 100 000 - in order to get all the bank that are stored inthe db:   see  for example a detailed page: https://thebanks.eu/banks/9563

I guess that this could be a good approach to iterate over all  the existing 9000 records...!?  What do you say!?

Comment: If you look at the response from the line ```response = requests.get(url)```, you're getting a `403` (forbidden) for each request. This page is probably blocking requests that aren't from a legit browser (It's protected by CloudFlare to protect against scraping and bots probably). Try Selenium maybe?

Comment: good day dear @eternal_white : many thanks for the reply and the hints. Awesome: well as for the selenium we can try the approach from Jacob Padilla - see 
https://github.com/jpjacobpadilla and  https://github.com/jpjacobpadilla/Google-Colab-Selenium - he provides interesting approach that makes Selenium running in Colab
- later the weekend i will try out and come back - many thanks for encouraging and for all your help!! You guy rock ;)

Comment: **update:** good evening dear Asish M. and  eternal_white
thank you very much for your comments and for sharing your ideas: Food for thoughts:  As for the Selenium - i think that this is a good idea - and for running it (selenium) on Google-Colab i have learned from Jacob Padilla
Jacob / @user:21216449 :: see Jacobs page:  https://github.com/jpjacobpadilla with the Google-Colab-Selenium: https://github.com/jpjacobpadilla/Google-Colab-Selenium and the default Options:

Comment: @lebrochet It's an argument error. You are passing both `chromedriver` and `chrome_options` which is not valid. Try to replace the line with this `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)`

Comment: many many thanks dear Lakshmanarao Simbadri - i am so happy that you have responded - your solutions down below are awesome - especially the second works very very well - many thansk for all you do! this is so great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website is **cloudflare** protected so it is better to use a proxy to bypass

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd
from pdb import set_trace
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import json

# Get your own api_key from scrapeops or some other proxy vendor
API_KEY = "api_key"
def get_scrapeops_url(url):
    payload = {'api_key': API_KEY, 'url': url}
    proxy_url = 'https://proxy.scrapeops.io/v1/?' + urlencode(payload)
    return proxy_url

# Function to scrape bank data from my URL
def scrape_bank_data(url):
    proxy_url = get_scrapeops_url(url)
    response = requests.get(proxy_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))

    # here we try to extract contact details
    contact_details = []
    contacts_nodes = dom.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'/contacts/')]/following-sibling::span")
    for contact in contacts_nodes:
        contact_str = contact.text
        # Web site link is inside 'a' tag hence using some conditions
        if not contact_str:
            contact_str = contact.xpath(".//a/@href")[0]
            # email is availble inside 'a' tag but it is returning email-protection url instead of email hence taking it from a json script
            if (contact_str and contact_str.count("email") > 0):
                json_str = dom.xpath("//script[contains(@type,'application') and contains(text(),'BankOrCreditUnion')]")[0].text
                data_dict = json.loads(json_str)
                contact_str = data_dict["email"]
        contact_details.append(contact_str.strip())

    return ", ".join(contact_details)

# the list of URLs for scraping bank data by country
urls = [
    "https://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Albania",
    # "https://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Andorra",
    #  we could add more URLs for other countries as needed
]

# List to store bank data
bank_data = []

# Iterate through the URLs and scrape bank data
for url in urls:
    proxy_url = get_scrapeops_url(url)
    response = requests.get(proxy_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
    bank_details = dom.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'products')]/div[contains(@class,'product')]")

    for bank in bank_details:
        bank_info = {}
        bank_url = bank.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'title')]/a/@href")[0].strip()
        bank_name = bank.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'title')]/a")[0].text.strip()
        country = bank.xpath(".//span[contains(text(),'Country')]/following::div/text()")[0].strip()
        bank_info = {"Bank Name": bank_name, "Country": country, "Website": bank_url}
        contacts = scrape_bank_data(bank_url)
        bank_info["Contacts"] = contacts
        print(bank_info)
        bank_data.append(bank_info)

#  and now we convert the list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(bank_data)

# subsequently we print the DataFrame
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                              Bank Name  Country                          Website                                           Contacts
0             Alpha Bank - Albania S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19331  Street of Kavaja, G - KAM Business Center, 2 f...
1     American Bank of Investments S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19332  Street of Kavaja, Nr. 59, Tirana Tower, Tirana...
2                       Bank of Albania  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19343  Sheshi “Skënderbej“, No. 1, Tirana, Albania, +...
3       Banka Kombetare Tregstare SH.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19336  Rruga e Vilave, Lundër 1, 1045, Tirana, Albani...
4                     Credins Bank S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19333  Municipal Borough no. 5, street "Vaso Pasha", ...
5   First Investment Bank, Albania S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19334  Blv., Tirana, Albania, +355 4 2276 702, +355 4...
6     Intesa Sanpaolo Bank Albania S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19335  Street “Ismail Qemali”, No. 27, Tirana, Albani...
7                  OTP Bank Albania S.A  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19337  Boulevard "Dëshmorët e Kombit", Twin Towers, B...
8                   Procredit Bank S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19338  Street "Dritan Hoxha", Nd. 92, H. 15, Municipa...
9                  Raiffeisen Bank S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19339  Blv., Tirana, Albania, +355 4 2274 910, +355 4...
10                     Tirana Bank S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19340  Street, Tirana, Albania, 2269 616, 2233 417, h...
11                      Union Bank S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19341  Blv. "Zogu I", 13 floor building, in front of ...
12          United Bank of Albania S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19342  Municipal Borough nr. 7, street, 1023, Tirana,...
```

If you wish to go with only **selenium** then `headless browser` and `undetected_chrome` won't help here. Both will get blocked by **Cloudflare**. It is working fine if you run it in your local PC with the local browser.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time
from lxml import etree

# Set up options for Chrome WebDriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')  # Add this option
chrome_options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'


# Define function to scrape bank data using Selenium
def scrape_bank_data_with_selenium(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)  # Let the page load completely
    html = driver.page_source
    dom = etree.HTML(str(html))
    driver.quit()

    # here we try to extract contact details
    contact_details = []
    contacts_nodes = dom.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'/contacts/')]/following-sibling::span")
    for contact in contacts_nodes:
        contact_str = contact.text
        # Web site link is inside 'a' tag hence using some conditions
        if not contact_str:
            contact_str = contact.xpath(".//a/@href")[0]
            # email is availble inside 'a' tag but it is returning email-protection url instead of email hence taking it from a json script
            if (contact_str and contact_str.count("email") > 0):
                json_str = dom.xpath("//script[contains(@type,'application') and contains(text(),'BankOrCreditUnion')]")[0].text
                data_dict = json.loads(json_str)
                contact_str = data_dict["email"]
        contact_details.append(contact_str.strip())

    return ", ".join(contact_details)

# List of URLs for scraping bank data by country
urls = [
    "https://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Albania",
    # "https://thebanks.eu/search?bank=&country=Andorra",
    # Add more URLs for other countries as needed
]

# List to store bank data
bank_data = []

# Iterate through the URLs and scrape bank data
for url in urls:
    # Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)  # Let the page load completely
    html = driver.page_source
    dom = etree.HTML(str(html))
    # Close the WebDriver
    driver.quit()

    bank_details = dom.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'products')]/div[contains(@class,'product')]")
    for bank in bank_details:
        bank_info = {}
        bank_url = bank.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'title')]/a/@href")[0].strip()
        bank_name = bank.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'title')]/a")[0].text.strip()
        country = bank.xpath(".//span[contains(text(),'Country')]/following::div/text()")[0].strip()
        bank_info = {"Bank Name": bank_name, "Country": country, "Website": bank_url}
        contacts = scrape_bank_data_with_selenium(bank_url)
        bank_info["Contacts"] = contacts
        print(bank_info)
        bank_data.append(bank_info)
        time.sleep(1)

# Convert the list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(bank_data)

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                              Bank Name  Country                          Website                                           Contacts
0             Alpha Bank - Albania S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19331  Street of Kavaja, G - KAM Business Center, 2 f...
1     American Bank of Investments S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19332  Street of Kavaja, Nr. 59, Tirana Tower, Tirana...
2                       Bank of Albania  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19343  Sheshi “Skënderbej“, No. 1, Tirana, Albania, +...
3       Banka Kombetare Tregstare SH.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19336  Rruga e Vilave, Lundër 1, 1045, Tirana, Albani...
4                     Credins Bank S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19333  Municipal Borough no. 5, street "Vaso Pasha", ...
5   First Investment Bank, Albania S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19334  Blv., Tirana, Albania, +355 4 2276 702, +355 4...
6     Intesa Sanpaolo Bank Albania S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19335  Street “Ismail Qemali”, No. 27, Tirana, Albani...
7                  OTP Bank Albania S.A  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19337  Boulevard "Dëshmorët e Kombit", Twin Towers, B...
8                   Procredit Bank S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19338  Street "Dritan Hoxha", Nd. 92, H. 15, Municipa...
9                  Raiffeisen Bank S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19339  Blv., Tirana, Albania, +355 4 2274 910, +355 4...
10                     Tirana Bank S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19340  Street, Tirana, Albania, 2269 616, 2233 417, h...
11                      Union Bank S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19341  Blv. "Zogu I", 13 floor building, in front of ...
12          United Bank of Albania S.A.  Albania  https://thebanks.eu/banks/19342  Municipal Borough nr. 7, street, 1023, Tirana,...
```

Comment: Hi there - awesome: many many thanks for the reply. This is so great that you lend a helping hand.  well the second solution works very very well.  I have not chrome but vivadli here - ( when started ) all works like a charm. i get the same results like you

the first one with scrapeops - does not work here: 

def get_scrapeops_url(url):
    payload = {'api_key': API_KEY, 'url': url}
    proxy_url = 'https://proxy.scrapeops.io/v1/?' + urlencode(payload)
    return proxy_url

I get back Empty dataframe 
Columns: []
Index:  []
Do i miss some thing here?  Many thanks for all you do!

Comment: Hi @malaga I hope you have replaced API_KEY variable with a valid api_key. If not then try to get an api_key from scrapeops or any other proxy vendor and check once.

Comment: hi - thank you for the hint - this idea regarding the api-keyfrom scrapeops is great i will try to get some of them - and  yes. then i will also tryout here .  have a great day. Greetings